# Problemas de iteracion con terraform for_each y aws_efs

Tags: aws, devops

Como puedo implementar **for_each** para todas las subnets en el modulo **aws_efs_mount_target**?

```
    resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "alpha" {
      file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
      subnet_id      = each.key
      for_each       = module.vpc.private_subnets
    }
```

Respuesta:
Error: Invalid for_each argument

on efs_mount.tf line 4, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "alpha":

4:   for_each       = module.vpc.private_subnets

```
├────────────────
│ module.vpc.private_subnets is tuple with 3 elements
```

The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of
strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.

Comment: Usa la función `toset`